# Ubuntu 15.10 boots slowly with no output of why

Tags: boot

Ubuntu takes long time to boot so I ran a `systemd-analyze` and a `systemd-analyse blame` and I don't really understand what is taking so long time. It takes me 3min and 24.135 seconds and the thing that takes the longest to boot is `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` with 326ms

Output from `systemd-analyse`

```
Startup finished in 4.855s (firmware) + 4.972s (loader) + 13.814s (kernel) + 3min 493ms (userspace) = 3min 24.135s
```

Output from `systemd-analyse`

```
           326ms NetworkManager-wait-online.service
           325ms dev-sda2.device
           268ms gpu-manager.service
           218ms apparmor.service
           173ms systemd-localed.service
           135ms ModemManager.service
           135ms accounts-daemon.service
           129ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
           126ms networking.service
           119ms systemd-logind.service
            98ms speech-dispatcher.service
            94ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            93ms rsyslog.service
            92ms ondemand.service
            91ms thermald.service
            90ms pppd-dns.service
            90ms grub-common.service
            89ms systemd-user-sessions.service
            87ms avahi-daemon.service
            85ms irqbalance.service
            83ms apport.service
            78ms NetworkManager.service
            75ms bluetooth.service
            57ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            47ms virtualbox.service
            47ms lightdm.service
            42ms systemd-udevd.service
            41ms udisks2.service
            33ms user@1000.service
            31ms console-setup.service
            29ms systemd-update-utmp.service
            28ms wpa_supplicant.service
            27ms plymouth-start.service
            27ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            25ms systemd-journald.service
            21ms systemd-modules-load.service
            21ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-265A\x2d395B.service
            19ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            19ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
            18ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            17ms plymouth-read-write.service
            16ms resolvconf.service
            16ms dns-clean.service
            14ms colord.service
            14ms kerneloops.service
            13ms ureadahead-stop.service
            13ms polkitd.service
            13ms boot-efi.mount
            12ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            11ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
            10ms kmod-static-nodes.service
            10ms upower.service
             9ms dev-mqueue.mount
             8ms ufw.service
             8ms systemd-journal-flush.service
             6ms systemd-sysctl.service
             6ms alsa-restore.service
```

System specs as requested

```
    BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: F.32
    Release Date: 03/02/2016
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 6144 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        Smart battery is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Function key-initiated network boot is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 15.50
    Firmware Revision: 33.86

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: HP Spectre x360 Convertible
    Version:  
    Serial Number: 5CD5495XVF
    UUID: 35444335-3934-5835-5646-465839344435
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: P1Q59EA#UUW
    Family: 103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=SPT

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: 804F
    Version: 33.56
    Serial Number: PFLJK018J9S0CC
    Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Base Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 25 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Chassis Version
    Serial Number: Chassis Serial Number
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 1
        <OUT OF SPEC> (0)
    SKU Number: Not Specified

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: TV Out
    External Connector Type: Mini Centronics Type-14
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2A
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM A
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2B
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Video
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB2
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: J6B2
    Type: x16 PCI Express
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Long
    ID: 0
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:01.0

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 11, 5 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: $HP$
    String 2: ABS 70/71 79 7A 7B 7C
    String 3: FBYTE#6b7N7R7W8AaBaHapaqasauawbVbhbnbzdUdXdpdq.NQ;BUILDID#15WW3K
    String 4: PT604#SUUW#DUUW;
    String 5:  
    String 6:  
    String 7:  
    String 8:  
    String 9:  
    String 10:  
    String 11:  
    String 12:  
    String 13:  

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
Portable Battery
    Location: Primary
    Manufacturer: 3332C
    Name: PK03056XL
    Design Capacity: 56540 mWh
    Design Voltage: 11400 mV
    SBDS Version: 1.1
    Maximum Error: Unknown
    SBDS Serial Number: 1B29
    SBDS Manufacture Date: 2015-10-09
    SBDS Chemistry: LION
    OEM-specific Information: 0x000A070C

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard IGD
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 64 kB
    Maximum Size: 64 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 64 kB
    Maximum Size: 64 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Instruction
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 3072 kB
    Maximum Size: 3072 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 12-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U3E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i5
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: E3 06 04 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 78, Stepping 3
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Voltage: 0.9 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 2800 MHz
    Current Speed: 2800 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0011
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0012
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0013
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0015
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: Row Of Chips
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom - on board
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Elpida
    Serial Number: Not Available
    Asset Tag: 0
    Part Number: EDFB164A1MA-JD-F
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
    Minimum voltage:  Unknown
    Maximum voltage:  Unknown
    Configured voltage:  1.200 V

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0015
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: Row Of Chips
    Set: None
    Locator: Bottom - on board
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Elpida
    Serial Number: Not Available
    Asset Tag: 0
    Part Number: EDFB164A1MA-JD-F
    Rank: 2
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
    Minimum voltage:  Unknown
    Maximum voltage:  Unknown
    Configured voltage:  1.200 V

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 8 GB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0015
    Partition Width: 2

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 221, 12 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 0C 19 00 01 01 00 01 07 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - ACPI

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0016
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0018
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 20, 35 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00100000000
    Ending Address: 0x001FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0017
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0018
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 130, 20 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        82 14 1C 00 24 41 4D 54 00 00 00 00 00 A5 BF 02
        C0 00 00 00

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 131, 64 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        83 40 1D 00 10 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
        F8 00 48 9D 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 0B 00
        8E 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 FE 00 FF FF 00 00 00 00
        00 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 76 50 72 6F 00 00 00 00

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 221, 26 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 1A 1E 00 03 01 00 01 07 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
        00 7C 00 03 00 00 05 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - CPU
        uCode Version
        TXT ACM version

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 221, 26 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 1A 1F 00 03 01 00 01 07 00 00 00 02 00 0A 00
        00 01 00 03 04 0B 00 00 8E 04
    Strings:
        Reference Code - ME 11.0
        MEBx version
        ME Firmware Version
        Consumer SKU

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 221, 68 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 44 20 00 09 01 00 01 07 00 00 00 02 03 FF FF
        FF FF FF 04 00 FF FF FF 21 00 05 00 FF FF FF 21
        00 06 00 FF FF FF FF FF 07 00 3E 00 00 00 00 08
        00 34 00 00 00 00 09 00 3E 00 00 00 00 0A 00 34
        00 00 00 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - SKL PCH
        PCH-CRID Status
        Disabled
        PCH-CRID Original Value
        PCH-CRID New Value
        OPROM - RST - RAID
        SKL PCH H Bx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH H Dx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH LP Bx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH LP Cx Hsio Version

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 221, 54 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 36 21 00 07 01 00 01 07 00 00 00 02 00 01 07
        00 00 00 03 00 01 07 00 00 00 04 05 FF FF FF FF
        FF 06 00 FF FF FF 08 00 07 00 FF FF FF 08 00 08
        00 FF FF FF 05 00
    Strings:
        Reference Code - SA - System Agent
        Reference Code - MRC
        SA - PCIe Version
        SA-CRID Status
        Disabled
        SA-CRID Original Value
        SA-CRID New Value
        OPROM - VBIOS

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Intel Stone Peak 2  7265 Combo /NON-vPro NGFF Combo Wireless-AC 7265
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:02:00.0

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Realtek PCIE CardReader
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:01:00.0

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 221, 96 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DD 60 24 00 0D 01 00 00 00 00 FF 00 02 00 FF FF
        FF FF FF 03 04 FF FF FF FF FF 05 06 FF FF FF FF
        FF 07 08 FF FF FF FF FF 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A
        00 FF FF FF FF FF 0B 00 21 56 00 00 00 0C 00 FF
        FF FF FF FF 0D 00 02 00 00 00 00 0E 00 FF FF FF
        FF FF 0F 00 FF FF FF FF FF 10 11 01 02 02 03 00
    Strings:
        Lan Phy Version
        Sensor Firmware Version
        Debug Mode Status
        Enabled 
        Performance Mode Status
        Disabled
        Debug Use USB(Disabled:Serial)
        Disabled
        ICC Overclocking Version
        UNDI Version
        EC FW Version
        GOP Version
        BIOS Guard Version
        Base EC FW Version
        EC-EC Protocol Version
        Royal Park Version
        BP1.2.2.0_RP03

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: Ctrl0Port1
    Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    External Reference Designator: Primary HDD Bay
    External Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
    Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 136, 6 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        88 06 26 00 00 00

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 14, 23 bytes
Group Associations
    Name: Firmware Version Info
    Items: 6
        0x0019 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x001E (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x001F (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0020 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0021 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0024 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 14, 8 bytes
Group Associations
    Name: $MEI
    Items: 1
        0x0000 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 219, 81 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        DB 51 29 00 01 03 01 45 02 00 90 06 03 10 86 00
        00 00 00 00 40 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 02
        FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
        FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        00
    Strings:
        MEI1
        MEI2
        MEI3

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 5
        en|US|iso8859-1
        fr|FR|iso8859-1
        es|ES|iso8859-1
        zh|TW|unicode
        zh|CN|unicode
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: check this link may be useful http://www.howtogeek.com/115797/6-ways-to-speed-up-ubuntu/

Comment: if you installing some thing like TLP it was causing slow boot to me after removing works fine the ideal boot time for you should not more than 25 sec 
an extra thing you should upgrade or install 16.04

Comment: I had TLP installed, but still over 3 mins to boot after I removed it.